# Difference between SYSDATE(),NOW(),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

As per my knowledge,

```
SYSDATE(),
NOW(),
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, and
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

in MySQL are synonyms for one another. They all returns same value,then why MySQL provides all of them ? Are there different scenarios where I can use specific one of them ?

Comment: Everything is here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: @Vipul hadiya : My question is Why MySQL provides such synonyms ? Read my complete question.

Comment: @Down voter : Provide proper comment what is wrong with this question ?

Comment: please spend some time to read it you will get answer

Comment: Nothing wrong, i am just telling what answer you want is there

Comment: @Vipul hadiya : Yes you are correct , but as you know there are lot of stuff  on internet for single technology,How could single person can go through all of it ?

Comment: @RaviJiyani certainly not with asking others to do the research for him!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They aren't all synonymous.

`SYSDATE()` is different than `NOW()`, in a significant way. As a demonstration:

```sql
SELECT NOW(), SYSDATE(), SLEEP(5), NOW(), SYSDATE()
```

The output might look like this:

(playing where's waldo to find the difference, its the return from the last expression that is different, a second invocation of SYSDATE, after a delay of 5 seconds, returns a value that differs by 5 seconds)

```
2018-03-01 11:09:19
2018-03-01 11:09:19
0
2018-03-01 11:09:19
2018-03-01 11:09:24
```

(There are some scenarios where we want to use `SYSDATE()` rather than `NOW()`)

MySQL provides a variety of expressions that can return the same result

`DATE(NOW())`  vs.  `CURRDATE()`

I suspect that this is large part due to a desire to make transition from other Relational DBMS easier, by more closely matching (where possible and appropriate) the function names and syntax used by Oracle, SQL Server, and so on.

Answer (score 26):

After reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp document, concluded that :

`NOW()` returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute. `NOW()` returns the time at which the function or triggering statement began to execute, but `SYSDATE()` returns the exact time at which it executes.

And `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` are synonyms for `NOW()`.